# Email Templates from a Packaged folder could not be found

Tags: email-template

I wanted to lookup an email template in my apex code. I tried to execute first an SOSL to check if I can find it, like

```
FIND {Generic} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING EmailTemplate(Name)
```

But it only gets the newly created email template when I would also want to get the packaged Email Template that is already provided from a packaged email template folder. How should I get that email template then?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a paid package? do you have license for that?

Comment: actually, I created the package and installed it to a sandbox to test it. It's okay in the patch org but as I test it on the sandbox, it's not getting the packaged email templates now. what might have happened?

Comment: it seems i can only access custom email templates but not the managed ones. any idea how to get the managed too?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no other solution but to clone the managed email templates so that the desired template can be accessed.